# Elasticsearch inverted index

Tags: elasticsearch, inverted-index

I am trying to understand inverted-index per index built for all documents added. I failed understand immutability of inverted-index. Does every new document addition replaced the existing inverted-index?

> This places a significant limitation either on the amount of data that
>   an index can contain, or the frequency with which the index can be
>   updated.

Although the document says that there is limitation on number of document added to index. Let's say the inverted-index reached its maximum document count limit, then when happen to new documents?

[Here is reface link from official site.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/making-text-searchable.html#_immutability)

Comment: you should read the next page of the guide https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/dynamic-indices.html about segment merging and updates

Comment: @PierreMallet thanks for the link. exactly I was looking for. Any explanation to second question of count limit?

Comment: Elastic create different segment to contains the data of your index. Segment can go up to 5Gb, but you can have as many segment as your want. But here is a limit to what Lucene can handle. See here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/_basic_concepts.html#getting-started-shards-and-replicas